# Unzipping a zip file directly in Google Cloud Bucket (GCS)

Tags: cloud-storage

I am using the Google Cloud and in one of the bucket (GCS)I have a folder which has sub folders and each sub folder has zip files of approximate 600MB to 1.5GB each.
If i have to give the count of the zip files i would say they are approximate about 2000+ zip files.

Each zip files has CSV files of varied size.
I have to unzip each file and then read the csv file and do operations on them.
My problem is that i am not able to unzip the files in the bucket it self. 
Right now, through a shell script, I am coping one sub folder at a time to my current working directory, unzipping it and then writing back to the bucket in the GCS and deleting the old unzip data and so on.
I am doing the one sub folder at a time because if i try to copy everything in a single go my current working directory runs out of space
I will need to do the above activity when ever i get new data and getting new data will be frequent
Is there a better way or smarter way to unzip the files in the Bucket(GCS) itself.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541026/how-do-i-unzip-a-zip-file-in-google-cloud-storage for some solutions.